# JSX/Photoshop: Toggling non selected layer visibility by name?

Tags: toggle, visibility, photoshop, layer, jsx

I'm using this piece for hide/show selected layer:

```
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.visible = !app.activeDocument.activeLayer.visible;
```

I wonder if there exist a way of toggling a non selected layer by it's name.

Many thanks

Update:

I got it working with this thing (I know, it must be cleaned):

```
function toggleLayer() {
  for( var i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.artLayers.length; i++) {
    if (app.activeDocument.artLayers[i].name == "theLayer"){
        app.activeDocument.artLayers[i].allLocked = false;
        app.activeDocument.artLayers[i].visible = !app.activeDocument.artLayers[i].visible;
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to know if we can do the same without the loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I did write. Unexpectedly it worked :P

```
function toggleLayer() {
  var tl = app.activeDocument.layers["theLayer"];
  tl.visible = !tl.visible;
}

toggleLayer();
```

Now, I have another doubt: Whats the difference between "layers" and "artLayers"?

Cheers